# Using Emacs for big big projects

Tags: search, emacs, editor, project

Maybe is a often repeated question here, but i can't find anything similar with the search.
The point is that i like to use Emacs for my personal projects, usually very small applications using C or python, but i was wondering how to use it also for my work, in which we have project with about 10k files of source code, so is veeeery big (actually i am using source insight, that is very nice tool, but only for windows), questions are:

- Searching: Which is the most convenient way to search a string within the whole project?
- Navigating throught the function: I mean something like putting the cursor over a function, define, var, and going to the definition
- Refactoring

Also if you have any experience with this and want to share your thoughts i will consider it highly interesting.

Br

Comment: What language is the large project in? C or Python, too?

Comment: Complete project includes C,C++,python,bash scripting ... but from my side, i am only modifying C and C++ files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My projects typically live in git, so I put this together to quickly search them:

```
;; There's something similar (but fancier) in vc-git.el: vc-git-grep
;; -I means don't search through binary files
(defcustom git-grep-switches "--extended-regexp -I -n --ignore-case"
  "Switches to pass to `git grep'."
  :type 'string)

(defun git-grep (command-args)
  (interactive
   (list (read-shell-command "Run git-grep (like this): "
                             (format "git grep %s -e "
                                     git-grep-switches)
                             'git-grep-history)))
  (let ((grep-use-null-device nil))
    (grep command-args)))
```

Comment: If anyone's reading this and doesn't have their project in git, I find ack is nicer than grep for searching code. It doesn't search as fast (though it's not much slower on a pretty big codebase) but it is much faster to type "ack blah" than "find . -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.h" -exec grep blah {} \;" :-)

Comment: How about M-x tags-search instead of grep?

Comment: The problem with M-x tags-search is that you must first create a TAGS file, and occasionally that's difficult.  For example, I don't think etags will do anything sensible with a Visual Studio build file, but I want to search through those, too.

Answer (score 10):

The "traditional" way of navigating C source files is to use "etags" to make a file called TAGS, then use ALT-. to go to functions across files.

For searching for strings in files, I usually use "grep". You could make a shell script with all the directories you want to search or something if you get tired of typing them in each time.

Comment: Actually, etags stands for emacs tags, which is just one of the formats that exuberant ctags can produce.  When exuberant ctags is invoked using the name etags, it produces emacs format tag files.  When it is invoked using the name ctags, it produces ctags format files.  Of course, you can also pass it command-line options to control which format is used regardless of the name used to invoke the tool.

Comment: very interesting, any special hint for using grep in more convenient way, i mean i found very slow to enter every time the grep options and search path

Comment: OK I removed the bit about exuberant.

Answer (score 6):

There is also the Emacs Code Browser. It makes exploring projects a lot simpler. See [here](http://ecb.sourceforge.net/) and [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsCodeBrowser) for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Regarding searches in the whole project, I find extremely  useful the **rgrep** command.

Also, **imenu** is quite handy to jump to a function definition in the same file.

These are my 2p.

Answer (score 3):

look to EDE from CEDET - it provide base support for projects...

Answer (score 3):

ECB is too heavyweight for my taste. I have had good results with xcscope. Needless to say it doesn't help too much with Python.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CScopeAndEmacs

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using TAGS as others have mentioned, I find [`igrep`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/igrep.el) and `igrep-find` very useful.  There is also Emacs' built in [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Grep-Searching.html) and `grep-find`, but I find their interface more clumsy.

My standard search is:

```
M-x igrep-find some_regexp RET ~/work_area/*.cxx
```

Which will look for all `*.cxx` files under `~/work/area`, and show results matching `some_regexp`.  Like all the search utilities, it populates a compilation-like buffer you can navigate using <kbd>C-x `</kbd> (aka <kbd>M-x next-error</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways that [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) can help with ***[projects](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects)***.  Likewise, [Bookmark+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) and even [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus).

These libraries can help you create, organize, and manage projects, wherever their files and directories might reside.  And they can help you navigate and search in various ways.

Some of the features are unique -- quite different from other approaches. I could list some of the project support here, but this is the best place to [start](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Support_for_Projects).